# Starting Swift REPL for iOS vs OSX

Tags: ios, macos, swift

How does one invoke the Swift REPL for iOS?  I tried the command line argument of `swift -sdk ...` and have looked, via `swift -h`, at the other invocation arguments but none jumps out at me.

```
$ swift
Welcome to Swift!  Type :help for assistance.
  1> import UIKit
<REPL>:1:8: error: no such module 'UIKit'
import UIKit
       ^
```

The Swift REPL runs in a Playground in 'iOS' mode on a Mac; just looking to get the same from the command line.

Comment: See [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43478888/3195266).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One way to do this is to create an iOS/OS X project and set a break point to interrupt the flow. Then, enter `repl` into the lldb console and enjoy.

For more on this one, watch WWDC 2014 session 409 - Introduction to LLDB and the Swift REPL.

[image: repl]