# Can I import my project code into the Swift REPL?

Tags: xcode, swift, swift-playground

The Swift REPL is great, but it would be even better if I could import the classes from an Xcode project. I tried switching to my project directory and running

```
$ swift
> import ProjectName
```

but I got:

```
error: no such module 'ProjectName'
```

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 16):

The Swift REPL includes a number of different options.  Use `swift -help` to see them.  For your case, if you've defined `ProjectName` as a framework target and in the target you've declared 'Defines Module' then you can access it with:

```
$ swift -F <install path with subdirectory ProjectName.framework>
> import ProjectName
```

Here is an example:

```
$ swift -F /Users/.../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Opus-bsjennhdtvmqrhejuabovdyxlqte/Build/Products/Debug/
Welcome to Swift!  Type :help for assistance.
  1> import OpusOSX
  2> version                    // var from framework
$R0: String = "Opus 1.0"
  3> any([1,3]) { 0 == $0 % 2 } // 'any()' in framework
$R1: Bool = false
  4> any([1,2,3]) { 0 == $0 % 2 } 
$R2: Bool = true
  4> any([1,2,3,4], conjoin ({ 0 == $0 % 2 }, { $0 >= 3 })) 
$R3: Bool = true
```

Comment: Can this work for an iOS app project, rather than a framework?

Comment: Probably not, for two reasons.  First, the `swift` program doesn't have any command line options for importing projects and second,  the `swift` program is not a cross-compiler and thus only works for MacOSX.  Note: you get a 'cross-compiler' using a IOS Playground in Xcode just not with the command line via `Swift`.

Comment: to use the REPL for iOS see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24385734/starting-swift-repl-for-ios-vs-osx/24388630#24388630

Comment: For standalone iOS swift repl with autocompletion and history navigation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43478888/3195266.