# Importing a framework build for testing in Swift REPL fails?

Tags: swift, macos, compilation, read-eval-print-loop

I have built my framework (mixed Swift and Objective-C) and its dependencies (Alamofire) for macOS; no compiler errors arise. The build products happily resides in `/Users/myuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproject-hash/Build/Products/Debug/`. The project was originally created as Cocoa Touch Framework; I added a macOS target manually (which took some wrangling).

Now I try to apply [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27882120/539599), calling

```
swift -F /Users/myuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproject-hash/Build/Products/Debug/
```

When I try `import Alamofire`, I get a whole slew of errors like this:

```
error: Alamofire debug map object file '/Users/myuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproject-hash/Build/Intermediates/Alamofire.build/Debug/Alamofire macOS.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Timeline.o' has changed (actual time is 0x58ef7cfd, debug map time is 0x58ef6d81) since this executable was linked, file will be ignored
```

This is confusing since I *just* built the framework. Also, why is the framework linking into `Intermediates`?

Finally:

```
error: Couldn't lookup symbols:
  __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftCoreGraphics
  __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftDispatch
```

This one also appears if I try `import MyProject` after the (failed?) `import Alamofire`.

If I directly `import MyProject` (in a fresh session), all of the `debug map object file...` errors happen, but not the `lookup symbols` one. When I try to instantiate a struct from `MyProject`, I *do* get the `Couldn't lookup symbols` error, this time on symbols from `MyProject`.

What is going on here? What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix or work around the issue?

When I use the release build, the errors are gone -- provided I do `import Alamofire; import MyProject`. Apparently the dependencies are not imported recursively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above was with Swift 3.0.2. I can not reproduce it with Swift 3.1.

*Nota bene:* It seems important to really do

```
import Alamofire
import MyProject
```

If you skip the first import, the import of `MyProject` won't fail but weird lookup errors (that do not mention Alamofire stuff at all) will happen.