# How can I use Swift REPL with iOS SDK

Tags: ios, swift

Can I run Swift REPL with iOS SDK?

I want to import and use `UIKit` in REPL, but no success.

```
$ xcrun --sdk iphonesimulator8.1 --show-sdk-path
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.1.sdk

$ xcrun --sdk iphonesimulator8.1 swift
Welcome to Swift!  Type :help for assistance.
  1> import UIKit
/var/folders/kb/xgglxb597sv6h8b744d5vft00000gn/T/lldb/92014/repl1.swift:2:8: error: no such module 'UIKit'
import UIKit
       ^

$ swift -sdk `xcrun --sdk iphonesimulator8.1 --show-sdk-path`
Welcome to Swift!  Type :help for assistance.
  1> import UIKit
/var/folders/kb/xgglxb597sv6h8b744d5vft00000gn/T/lldb/91881/repl1.swift:2:8: error: no such module 'UIKit'
import UIKit
       ^

  1> import Cocoa
  2>
```

I'm using Xcode Version 6.1 (6A1052d)

Answer (score 8):

You may achieve it by running `repl` from `lldb`, which attached to iOS application process (of your Xcode project).

1. Build project in Xcode, or:

   ```
   $ xcrun xcodebuild -configuration Debug -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 7,OS=10.3' clean build
   ```
2. Start [standalone](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/gdb_to_lldb_transition_guide/document/lldb-terminal-workflow-tutorial.html) `lldb` for your iOS project:

   ```
   $ xcrun lldb -- $DerivedData/$AppName/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/$AppName.app
   (lldb) process attach --name '$AppName' --waitfor
   ```

   You may find useful `platform select ios-simulator` and `platform connect $UDID` commands here.
3. Run your iOS application in iOS simulator from Xcode

   - Or from command line:

     1. Boot simulator

        - From `instruments`:

          ```
          $ xcrun instruments -w "`xcrun instruments -s | grep 'iPhone 7 (10.3)' | head -1`"
          ```
        - Or as an application:

          ```
          $ open -a "Simulator" --args -CurrentDeviceUDID "`xcrun instruments -s | grep 'iPhone 7 (10.3)' | head -1 | sed -E -e 's/[^][]*\[([^][]*)\][^][]*/\1/g'`"
          ```
     2. Install the application on simulator, and launch it:

        ```
        $ xcrun simctl install booted $DerivedData/$AppName/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/$AppName.app
        $ xcrun simctl launch booted $AppBundleID
        ```

        Also, you can even use `xcrun simctl launch --wait-for-debugger` and start `lldb` later.
   - Or with [ios-sim](https://github.com/phonegap/ios-sim):

     1. Optionally boot simulator & install the application:

        ```
        $ ios-sim start --devicetypeid 'iPhone-7, 10.3'
        $ ios-sim install --devicetypeid 'iPhone-7, 10.3' $DerivedData/$AppName/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/$AppName.app
        ```
     2. Launch it:

        ```
        $ ios-sim launch --devicetypeid 'iPhone-7, 10.3' $DerivedData/$AppName/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/$AppName.app
        ```
4. Attach to process in iOS simulator in `lldb`:

   ```
   (lldb) continue
   (lldb) process interrupt
   ```
5. Run `swift` repl.

   ```
   (lldb) repl
    1> import UIKit
    2>
   ```

Furthermore, as opposed to `swift` `repl` in Xcode debug terminal emulator, here we have working source autocompletion and command history navigation.

Comment: This is an amazing answer.

Answer (score 4):

The Swift REPL currently does not support iOS device or iOS simulator.

Comment: Has this changed?