# UIGraphicsEndImageContext could not be resolved while running Swift through command line

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, clang, llvm

I am running Swift through the command line:

```
xcrun swift -sdk $(xcrun --show-sdk-path --sdk iphonesimulator --find clang) -
```

Then I am passing in

```
import UIKit
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(500, 500), false, 0.0)
UIColor.blackColor().setStroke()
let path = UIBezierPath()
path.moveToPoint(CGPointMake(100, 0))
// some path stuff...
path.dynamicType
let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

The compiler is returning:

```
LLVM ERROR: Program used external function '_UIGraphicsEndImageContext' which could not be resolved!
```

Is there a way that I can run this and include the needed libraries to run `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()`?

I tried finding the way to include other libraries but I thought that this method would be included in UIKit.

**EDIT**
I tried adding in frameworks to the command but I am not sure what framework I'd need to add. I tried the following.

```
xcrun swift -v -F /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks -F /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/OtherFrameworks -F /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks -sdk $(xcrun --show-sdk-path --sdk iphonesimulator --find clang)
```

This did not work either.

**NOT A DUPLICATE**
This is not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26899664/how-can-i-use-swift-repl-with-ios-sdk) because this is able to import `UIKit` and `Foundation`. If you write the following code for the REPL it works:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
print("works")
```

In that case it does not throw errors. I also [posted an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33420998/974407) there which works.

Comment: @rob-mayoff This is not a duplicate of that question. I can import UIKit and Foundation without error. It is the use of UIGraphics that causes an error. And specifically an LLVM error. Completely different question.

Comment: Actually... the compiler doesn't yell when you import UIKit *but* it will fail as soon as you will try to use an UIKit object. Your `print` works because it comes from Foundation but anything UIKit won't work because it's specific to iOS SDK and it's not compatible -yet?- with the repl.

Comment: @EricD. You are right this is a dup.